# Why choose a specific team comp based on your map side?

Tags: league-of-legends

Would a team specifically choose different champs based on their map side? Bottom side has advantage late game on Baron control, while top side has advantage early game on Dragon control. Or do teams just pick their champs and team comps without the map being a factor? What specific team comps would be good for early or late game?

Comment: i personally can't think of anything but definately not making it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a large difference between the different sides, however, it is easier to run a double AP team on the blue team, since the blue buff is between top and mid lane. Also, Lee Sin does have the ability to sneak dragon on the blue team, since his q can allow him to hop over the back wall of dragon, and possibly avoid wards if dragon itself is not warded. However, it is easier for purple team to steal blue team's blue buff, since only 3 people can easily protect blue's blue, while 4 people can protect purple's blue.

Answer (score 0):

Entire team comps are not chosen based solely on map sides, however lane choices are definitely impacted, which may indirectly affect team comps.

Blue side's bottom lane can take the double golems before the minions reach the turrets and thus have a level advantage immediately into the laning phase (hitting the critical level 2 and 6 before the opposing bottom lane).  This can be taken advantage of with kill lanes such as Tristana/Alistar or Leona/Corki.

Purple side is also more susceptible to counter-jungling from the top lane (championed by M5 recently) by champions who push the lane (see: Shyvana).  Blue side's camps are farther for a top lane to counter jungler and thus more dangerous as the Wolf camp is deep into enemy territory and adjacent to the middle lane.  Purple's double golems however, are close to top and far from mid, making them exceptional targets for counterjungling by a pushing top laner.

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't any specific team compositions that favor blue side anywhere except for an aggressive top lane that can push the wave and counter jungle.  Bottom really doesn't matter when it comes to taking the double golems  any two champions can kite them reasonably well even if they have no range.